# How to copy array of an object into the array of another object in c#?

Tags: c#

I have defined 2 classes and some objects like these:

```
public class MyClass
{
public int[] numbers { get; set; }
//some other properties
}

public class DemoClass
{
//some other properties
public int[] numbers { get; set; }
//some other properties
}

var myObject= new MyClass();
var sourceObject= new DemoClass{
                       numbers={1,2,3}
                       //other properties 
                      }
```

Now, I want to copy the array of sourceObject into the array of myObject. What is the best approach?

```
myObject.numbers= sourceObject.numbers;
```

or

```
myObject.numbers= (int[])sourceObject.numbers.Clone();
```

Comment: I'd use `.ToArray()`... But really it mostly taste choice... and a bit of whether you actually need a "copy" (as the title says) or the same reference as the sample code in the post shows.

Comment: Note that your first option does **not** create a copy at all, but rather keep a reference to the same array from `sourceObject.numbers`.

Comment: @wohlstad yeah I know that, and actually I think it is not a good one...

Comment: This is not opinion-based as one option does and one doesn't actually create a copy of the data. I'd go for `myObject.numbers= sourceObject.numbers.ToArray();` , too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this:

```
myObject.numbers = sourceObject.numbers.ToArray();
```

Since `sourceObject.numbers` is an `int[]` then, under the hood, LINQ uses `Array.Copy` anyway.